# Get table names from a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched through a bunch of websites and I have not come across any code or tutorial which has gone through the specifics of obtaining the table names from a single database.

Assuming I have 4 databases and I want the names of all the tables within the database called `mp21`, what query can I use?

Comment: What flavour RDBMS are you using - SQL Server, MySQL or other..?

Comment: Also, what programming language / framework are you using? .NET, Java, COBOL...? Or do you want to do it using only SQL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: This works. All I had to do was add "AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mp21'" to the end and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In MySQL this will list all databases:

```
show databases;
```

For each of these you can do:

```
use <database_name>;
```

and then

```
show tables;
```

Comment: USE mp21 SHOW TABLES doesn't work either. Also another code I tried before hand.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL SERVER, you can just use -

```
select * from sys.tables
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but this doesn't work in my SQL. I'm pretty sure it's the latest version, but I keep getting errors. Thanks though.

Comment: @Syed Abdul Rahman - This query works in SQL Server, not in mySql. I pressume you are using MySql and hence this would not work. Since you had not mentioned your RDBMS in question, I sent you SQL server query. Anyway you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
use mp21
SELECT name FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

Comment: Tried this before. I am not sure why, but sys doesn't work with my queries.

Comment: Which database system are you using, sqlserver?

Answer (score 1):

I used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

It gives me table name as well as sysDiagram(database diagram generated for that database)

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about .net code then You need [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) :

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;



public static List<Table> GetTables(string connection, string databaseName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connection))
                throw new ArgumentException("connection is null or empty.", "connection");

            Server srv = getServer(connection);
            return srv.Databases[databaseName].Tables.Cast<Table>().ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MySQL query you asked.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mp21'
```