# Iterating rows with Pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc to return a number of rows which are dumped into a JSON and sent to a server.  I would like to iterate my SQL table and return all records.   I am using `cursor.fetchall()` now, and the program returns one record.  As shown below.  When I use `fetchone` an error is returned `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'SRNUMBER'`  and `fetchmany` returns one record as well. How do I successfully return all records?  I am using Python 2.6.7

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
import requests



    connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=ServiceRequest; UID=SA;PWD=pwd'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
                SELECT SRNUMBER, FirstName, LastName, ParentNumber
     FROM MYLA311 """)

    rows = cursor.fetchone()



    objects_list = []
    for row in rows:
         d = collections.OrderedDict()
         d['SRNUMBER']= row.SRNUMBER
         d['FirstName']= row.FirstName
         d['LastName']= row.LastName
         d['ParentNumber']= row.ParentNumber



    objects_list.append(d)

    output = {"MetaData": {},
    "SRData": d}

    print output

    j = json.dumps(output)
    print json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`
```

Output for fetchall and fetchmany:

```
{
    "MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {
        "FirstName": "MyLAG", 
        "LastName": "ThreeEleven", 
        "ParentNumber": "021720151654176723", 
        "SRNUMBER": "1-3580171"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use code from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523148/366335) to build a list of dictionaries for the value of `output['SRData']`, then JSON encode the `output` dict as normal.

```
import pyodbc
import json

connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=ServiceRequest; UID=SA;PWD=pwd'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT SRNUMBER, FirstName, LastName, ParentNumber FROM MYLA311""")

# build list of column names to use as dictionary keys from sql results
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

output = {"MetaData": {}, "SRData": results}

print(json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: for what it's worth,  fetchall() will not work if there's just too many rows that can be fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the line

```
objects_list.append(d)
```

needs to be inside the for loop, not outside.