# Pyodbc + MSSQL 2017 generates JSON response to python app

Tags: json, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

My python app calls MSSQL 2017 function trough pyodbc and function query response is JSON formatted on the server side.

`cursor.execute("SELECT dbo.fnInvoiceJSON(%s,%s);" % (posted,vat)) 
row = cursor.fetchone()`

Response that returns in the app is a `class 'pyodbc.Row` like it should be.
I can pass this response trough `requests.post` to other API call if i convert this to to string.

Is there any way to convert this response a accessible python dict / JSON object?

Comment: If `fetchone()` returns a row object containing a single column then you can use `fetchval()` instead. Details [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rows returned by pyodbc are not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715593/rows-returned-by-pyodbc-are-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Thanks @Gord Thompson. `fetchval()` doses the trick. Now return object is string and from there i can convert it to dict ´json.loads(row)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the question, under pyodbc `fetchone()` returns a `pyodbc.Row` object and `fetchall()` returns an array of `pyodbc.Row` objects.

However, pyodbc also supports a [fetchval()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval) method that will return the value in the first column of the first row in the result set (similar to the `ExecuteScalar` method in C#). `fetchval()` returns the value as the corresponding Python type (e.g., string, None, etc.).