# How to reference column names with dashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following works as expected, however, I'm stuck on referencing the specific column names.  For example, print just `[OD-Nr]` or  `[OD-Title]`

I know if I used an alias, it would be as simple as `print(row.id)`, but I'd rather avoid aliases if possible.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xxxx;'
                      'Database=xxxx;'
                      'UID=xxxx;'
                      'PWD=xxxx;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select [OD-Nr],[OD-Title] from [dbo].[OD]")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try enclosing the column names with single quotes or backticks perhaps?

Comment: use cursor.description to get the column names and then proceed from there, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519385/output-pyodbc-cursor-results-as-python-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking gregory's suggestion, I looked at `cursor.description` and added a little twist to convert the array of column names to lowercase.

It would be nice to know any alternative methods.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xxxx;'
                      'Database=xxxx;'
                      'UID=xxxx;'
                      'PWD=xxxx;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select [OD-Nr],[OD-Title] from [dbo].[OD]")

aCol=[column[0].lower() for column in cursor.description]
iCol=aCol.index('od-title'.lower() )

for row in cursor:
    print(row[iCol])
```